# How to create a Calendar of a specific type?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, eventkit

How can I create a calendar of a specific type? All calendars created with + calendarWithEventStore: are created with type Local:

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKCalendar *cal = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore:store];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate over the available types and pull the one you want.

```
EKCalendar* cal = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore: self.eventStore];

EKSource* sourceForType = nil;

for (EKSource* src in self.eventStore.sources)
{
    if (src.sourceType == calType)
    {
        sourceForType = src;
    }
}

cal.source = sourceForType;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not forgot to place save calendar statement for creating your calendar.
    **–saveCalendar:commit:error:**  .
 The EKEventStore property for saving the calendar to the database.

Happy Coding,Arun